# How can I display only current png and hide others in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, images, display

I have a lot of inline images and I want to disply only 1 in buffer and hide others while viewing.

With `M-x org-toggle-inline-images` I can do this for the entire buffer, but it's too much for me.

So, how can I do this?

Update:
With `M-x org-open-at-point` I can preview the image, but I would like to be able to compare multiple images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is anything ready-made, but it does not take too much work to create something like that. The main question is what interface you find convenient.

`org-toggle-inline-images` (bound to `C-c C-x C-v`) calls the function `org-display-inline-images` underneath the covers (that is mentioned in the doc string BTW - do `C-h f org-toggle-inline-images` to see it).

If you do `C-h f org-display-inline-images`, you will see that it is capable of displaying images *in a region*:

> (org-display-inline-images &optional INCLUDE-LINKED REFRESH BEG END)
>
> ...
>
> BEG and END define the considered part.  They default to the
> buffer boundaries with possible narrowing.

So one way to go is to narrow the buffer to a region that contains just the image you want with `C-x n n`, toggle inline images with `C-c C-x C-v` and widen the buffer with `C-x n w`. That's probably too much work so we can write a more targeted function:

```el
(defun ndk/org-display-inline-images (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (org-display-inline-images nil nil beg end))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c v") #'ndk/org-display-inline-images)
```

The function passes the region to `org-display-inline-images`, so you avoid the narrowing/widening of the buffer. We also define a keybinding to it, so it can be called easily. Now all you have to do is select a region that contains one or more images, press `C-c v` and the image(s) within the region will be inlined. You can get rid of the inlining with `C-c C-x v`, i.e. calling our old friend `org-toggle-inline-images`.

If that's still too much work, you can write a more specialized function that determines the region around the link at point on its own and passes that region to `org-display-inline-images`. It's more limited in the sense that it will only look for one image around point, never more than one, but you might prefer that:

```el
(defun ndk/org-display-inline-image-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((context (org-element-context (org-element-at-point)))
         (type (org-element-type context))
         (beg  (plist-get (cadr context) :begin))
         (end  (plist-get (cadr context) :end)))
     (when (eq type 'link)
        (org-display-inline-images nil nil beg end))))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c v") #'ndk/org-display-inline-image-at-point)
```

This version uses the `org-element` parser to figure out the "thing" around point and it finds a link, it gets the beginning and the end of the region that the link occupies and passes that region to `org-display-inline-images` as before.

Putting your cursor on a link and saying `C-c v` then inlines the link. Moving to another link and doing `C-c v` there undoes the previous inlining and inlines the new link. If any inlining is showing, then using the toggle function with `C-c C-x C-v` gets rid of all inlining.